# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tava acompanhando um projeto em um tutorial e esbarrei nesse problema, como vocês sabem em tutoriais não se explica os erros das coisas então vim aqui, ainda tô aprendendo.

```
addEventListenerAll(element, events, fn){

    events.split(' ').forEach(event => { //ERRO

        element.addEventListener(event, fn, false)
    })
}


initButtonsEvents(){

    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#buttons > g, #parts > g')

    buttons.forEach((btn, index)=>{

        this.addEventListenerAll(btn, 'click drag', e => {

            console.log(btn.className.baseVal.replace('btn-', ''))
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Caro Stenio, o código parece correto, provavelmente é outra coisa ou em outro lugar, não tem sentido o seu código, ele provavelmente nem é JS, deve ser typescript, precisamos q vc explique melhor como esta executando, pq aqui funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Quando for assim é bom pesquisar o erro aqui mesmo no site. Tem uma quantidade imensa de perguntas e respostas similares (nem deveria ter tantas, na verdade). Conteúdo duplicado não é benéfico para o nosso modelo. E sempre que postar algo, forneça um [mcve]. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias variantes desse erro espalhadas pelas internet, e referem sempre ao método executado, que no seu caso é o `split`.

A mensagem diz:

> Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Isso significa que você está a tentar chamar `split` sobre algo que está `undefined`, que é basicamente aqui:

```
events.split(' ').forEach(event => {
          ^---- split chamado aqui
  ^------------ events está undefined
```

A causa disto é o valor do objeto que você está a tratar, que se espera que tenha conteúdo mas no seu caso não tem. Resumindo, era esperado que o seu parâmetro `events` tivesse conteúdo mas ele está vazio porque:

- Ou não foi passado na função, quando a chamou. Ex:

  ```
  let element = document.getElementById("exemplo");
  obj.addEventListenerAll(element);
  // ----------------------------^
  // |
  // faltou passar o events como segundo parametro e por isso vai ficar undefined
  // neste exemplo até o terceiro parametro fn vai ficar undefined
  ```
- Ou passou ele sendo que esqueceu de colocar valor. Ex:

  ```
  let element = document.getElementById("exemplo");
  let events;  // <--- não foi inicializado logo fica undefined
  let fn = () => {};
  obj.addEventListenerAll(element, events, fn);
  ```

Comment: O Split no caso era pra ter sido aplicado em cima do 'click drag' e o próprio seria aplicado em vários botões, então pelo que tu disse eu tô errando o caminho do split para o 'click drag'.

Tô quebrando a cabeça aqui tentando ajustar isso kkk

Comment: @StênioAmorim É como eu mencionei na resposta, ou não passou os dados certos à função ou passou eles vazios. Tem de confirmar o que está a ser passado à função. Para tal pode fazer uso de `console.log`, ferramentas de depuração, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Significa que a variável `events` está vazia.

A parte do seu código colada acima não parece que traria esse erro. Pode ser que sua função esteja sendo chamada a partir de outro lugar.

Sugestão:

1. Edite o seu código, adicionando a linha `debugger;` antes do `events.split`.
2. Abra o developer tools (F12) e dê um refresh (F5);
3. Execute a ação que faça rodar o código em análise, o depurador vai parar na linha onde você colocou o `debugger`
4. Avalie se `events` está vazio (passando o mouse por cima ou digitando no console, pra abrir o console aperte "esc" com o cursor focado na dev tools).
5. Haverá na dev tools uma seção chamada "Call Stack" ou "Pilha de chamadas". Analise esta seção pra verificar de onde sua função foi chamada. Você pode navegar livremente por todas as funções na lista e ver os valores das variáveis;
6. Caso necessário, adicione novos breakpoints (ou adicionando o texto "debugger", ou clicando em cima de um número de linha), então rode o código novamente e repita as análises, até chegar mais próximo da causa fonte do problema.